# Script de Bootstrap modal emite error (Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, modal

me encuentro con el siguiente problema. La consola del navegador me emite un error en mi , es el siguiente **Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined**.

Adjunto imagen de la consola de mi navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjuntaré mi código:

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.view-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var numdoc_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('numdoc_id').text();

    // alert('Hello');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "controllers/code.php",
      data: {
        'view_modal_atencion_paciente': true,
        'documento_id': numdoc_id,
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('.internacion_paciente_modal').html(response);
        $('#pacienteMODAL').modal(show);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Las librerías que estoy usando para este script son: jQuery y Bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Pero es que así no se usa el modal en Bootstrap 4.x. Revisa la documentación.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio, plantearé el script de la forma correcta, según la documentación :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la [documentación de `.modal('show')`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalshow)) puedes comprobar que el parámetro es una cadena de caracteres. Tú estás usando una variable que no está definida.

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería:

```
$('#pacienteMODAL').modal('show');
```

Comment: Efectivamente Gabriel, agradezco tu ayuda ya que esto me funcionó y el modal se ejecuta.
 Quería hacerte una última pregunta, si me permites, cuando está abierto no logro cerrarlo con ninguna de las opciones disponibles (el ícono "x" y el botón "CERRAR").
 Muchas gracias.